# write function inside function in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, closures

I have JavaScript Closure methods I need to convert in to TypeScript. I am not able to do that. Please help me. How to write a function inside
a function in TypeScript?

```js
var postPonedMethod1 = function() {
  var postPonedMethod2 = function() {
    this.getClaimNotices();
    this.gridServices.get();
    //$scope.gridServicesReciepts.get();
    $scope.setDataLoading(false);
  };
  postPonedMethod2();
}
```

Comment: unsure how it is any different in typescript. What is not working when you "converted it" into typescript?

Comment: Yes, @epascarello is right, typescript does not touch the logic of the code, it only adds types during the development, once you build your code, there's only javascript left

Comment: I am not access the method which is written in component class body.  this.getClaimNotices();
    this.gridServices.get();
I am getting error of undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the use of `this`: `postPonedMethod2` refers to `this`, but it isn't a function defined on a class or object. If you're using popular TypeScript options [`--noImplicitThis`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitThis) or [`--strict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict), TypeScript will complain, because it is possible that you will eventually call `postPonedMethod2` in a way that does not provide the expected `this` instance. In fact, in JavaScript's ["strict mode" (`"use strict";`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) you might find that [`this` is undefined where it wasn't before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#function_context).

> In strict mode, however, if the value of `this` is not set when entering an execution context, it remains as `undefined`, as shown in the following example:
>
> ```js
> function f2() {
>   'use strict'; // see strict mode
>   return this;
> }
>
> f2() === undefined; // true
> ```

If possible, I'd switch to [defining your AngularJS component as a class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35451652/1426891), calling `this.postPonedMethod1()` and `this.postPonedMethod2()` for clarity.

In general in TypeScript, the solution is to type the "this" outside a class is to define an argument called `this` as your function's first parameter, which tells TypeScript what type to expect. To temporarily get through the problem, though, you can explicitly set `this: any`. **This defeats the purpose of TypeScript here,** because `any` provides no type checking at all, but it would allow you to solve the problem later in a different commit.

That fixes the typing, but you'll still need to ensure that the value of `this` is set correctly where you call `postPonedMethod2`. This would mean one of:

- Using an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `() => {` instead of `function () {` for `postPonedMethod2`. An arrow function explicitly does not redefine `this`.
- Calling [`bind(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) where `postPonedMethod2` is defined, or using [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) as in `postPonedMethod2.call(this)` where you call it.
- Avoiding `"use strict"` with [`--noImplicitUseStrict`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitUseStrict), if you're otherwise trying to emit a module.
- Saving the outer value of `this` to a place where it won't be redefined, as I show below.

```
var postPonedMethod1 = function() {
  var postPonedMethod2 = function() {
    this.getClaimNotices(); // error: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
    this.gridServices.get(); // error: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.
    //$scope.gridServicesReciepts.get();
    $scope.setDataLoading(false);
  };
  postPonedMethod2();
}

var fixedPostPonedMethod1 = function(this: any) { // Do better than "any" if you can.
  var component = this;                           // Store the enclosing "this".
  var postPonedMethod2 = function() {
    component.getClaimNotices();
    component.gridServices.get();
    //$scope.gridServicesReciepts.get();
    $scope.setDataLoading(false);
  };
  postPonedMethod2();                             // You could also call "bind".
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer i am new to type script this was bothering me as i am converting some one else code from angular js to type script.

Answer (score -1):

It works for me like below

```js
var postPonedMethod1 = () => {
  var postPonedMethod2 = () => {
    this.getClaimNotices();
    this.gridServices.get();
    //$scope.gridServicesReciepts.get();
    $scope.setDataLoading(false);
  };
  postPonedMethod2();


}
```

Comment: This is the same code that throws errors when you click "Run code snippet" as is present in the question. This would be an okay comment (albeit the same as existing ones), but does not make a good answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).